# How to keep data when run test in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Every time I run test. Rails will delete my data from table. I have million of record in my table for testing search performance and corrective. I can't add data every time I run test.

How to tell rails "Please don't delete data in this table" when i run test.

ps.

I found this link

[How do I run Rails integration tests without dropping DB contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433724/how-do-i-run-rails-integration-tests-without-dropping-db-contents)

It's maybe relate to my problems but I don't know where to put his code in my rails project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very similar to neokain's previous post, however, his didn't work on Rails 3 for me.
I went ahead and dropped this into my Rakefile at the root of the app and when I run test:units, it doesn't blow away all of my existing tables:

```
Rake::TaskManager.class_eval do
  def delete_task(task_name)
    @tasks.delete(task_name.to_s)
  end
  Rake.application.delete_task("db:test:purge")
  Rake.application.delete_task("db:test:prepare")
end

namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :purge do
    end
    task :prepare do
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah heck. I forgot that rake spec did this... For other googlers, this also came up for me when running rake spec while also using database_cleaner.  It was blowing away my seed data that I thought I had properly masked with db cleaner so IT wouldn't blow it away.  But this method works great.  Sometimes "rails being helpful" is really a pain in the, uh, rails...

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4 I end up with following

```
# lib/tasts/test.rake
# Do not drop database for tests
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'test'
  Rake::TaskManager.class_eval do
    def delete_task(task_name)
      @tasks.delete(task_name.to_s)
    end
  end

  Rake.application.delete_task("db:test:load")

  namespace :db do
    namespace :test do
      task :load do
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The "rake test" task always runs db:test:prepare which will recreate your database.

You can add this somewhere in lib/tasks:

```
if ENV['NO_DB']
  namespace :db do
    namespace :test do
      task :prepare do
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then run `NO_DB=1 rake test`. Also when you use autotest instead of the rake tasks the DB won't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I try to do allow first answer but not work.

I search and found this [www.pervasivecode.com](http://www.pervasivecode.com/blog/2007/09/22/making-rails-raketest-not-drop-your-pgsql-database/) and I modify code from first answer like this:

```
if ENV['NO_DB']
  Rake::TaskManager.class_eval do
    def delete_task(task_name)
      @tasks.delete(task_name.to_s)
    end
    Rake.application.delete_task("db:test:purge")
  end

  namespace :db do
   namespace :test do
    task :prepare do
    end
   end
  end
end
```

Then run command test allow first answer. Database test is not drop.