# Cucumber keeps deleting all the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Silly cucumber. This is what I got my env.rb :

```
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false

# begin
#   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
# rescue NameError
#   raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
# end
```

And in my feature I have this :

```
@javascript
@no-txn
Feature: AwesomeSauce
```

So what might still be invoking this DatabaseCleaner to ruin my day?

Comment: You mean it's deleting all your data at the very beginning of the run? And by data do you mean fixture data as opposed to whatever data you happened to have in your test database before you ran the tests?

Comment: Typically, all the data gets cleaned up between scenarios. I'd add data in for the scenario you will run.

Comment: How are you invoking your test run - Guard or Rake or other?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rake it's the db:test:purge that's doing it.  Someone else had already written the code for an answer here [How to keep data when run test in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158407/how-to-keep-data-when-run-test-in-rails) saving me the effort :-)

```
Rake::TaskManager.class_eval do
  def delete_task(task_name)
    @tasks.delete(task_name.to_s)
  end
  Rake.application.delete_task("db:test:purge")
  Rake.application.delete_task("db:test:prepare")
end

namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :purge do
    end
    task :prepare do
    end
  end
end
```

That should do the job.