# How do we configure rails to not clear out the test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are trying to rebuild an app in rails.  So we already have all of our tables in place.  While configuring the `database.yml` file, we found the following comment:

```
# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
```

We don't want to wipe out our test database.  Is there a way to disable this option?

Comment: To clarify, our test database is used by a server on our test environment, so that end users can see what things look like before we deploy to production.  We don't want to use this test database for automated tests.

Comment: That sounds more like a staging database.

Comment: Does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433724/how-do-i-run-rails-integration-tests-without-dropping-db-contents

Comment: @jvillian This is exactly it.  I guess we were confused because be call our staging environments test environments.  Is there a way to rename the `test` environment to `integration-test` so that future developers at our company don't get confused?

Comment: I don't know. But why don't you just update that comment with a longer comment explaining your company nomenclature?

Answer (score 0):

Move your "test" database settings to the "development" section of `database.yml`, and put a new database name in the "test" section.

And use it, with lots of fixtures in your test fixture files. Test Driven Development is a great way to develop twice as fast with 1/10th of the bugs.

Comment: We use TDD, but we prefer to keep our tests as decoupled from our database as possible.